# Дочерняя тема WP, как заменить файлы в папках?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создаю дочернюю тему в WordPress, всё как надо. Стили благополучно работают, файлы корневой директории заменяют файлы родительской. А вот файлы в папках напрочь игнорируются. Много гуглил, пытался решить сам, но всё тщетно.

Может, кто уже сталкивался с этим, как это решить?

Comment: Не все файлы можно заменить автоматически. Всё зависит от того, как их вызывает основная тема. Что за тема у вас?

Answer (score 1):

Как настроено подключение к родительской теме?
В functions.php дочерней темы должно быть так:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> всё как надо.

"Как надо" - не однозначно. В устаревшем русском переводе подключение уже не "как надо". "Как надо" - [в новом кодексе](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet)

> А вот файлы в папках напрочь игнорируются.

Всё правильно. Вне зависимости от того - дочка это или нет автоматом подтягиваются только [шаблоны](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) и файл функций. См [создание тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC).

Для того, чтобы ВП узнал о вложенных и др файлах - нужно их подключать. 
Но как правило в дочке этого не нужно делать - теряется ж сам смыл дочки.

Нужно либо использовать хуки либо из "внутреннего" файла родителя взять нужную функцию и поместив ей в файл функций дочки исправить как нужно. 
Но тут может быть проблема, если родитель не подготовлен для работы с дочками. Напр нет проверки существования функций. Тогда придется решать эти конфликты индивидуально.